# what input do scala case classes accept?

Tags: scala

The code below seems to work fine. But my question is that why the function is defined to take Strings as input but on the bottom, it has accepted some input integers?

case class

```
TempData(year:Int, month:String, Prec:Double, Maxtemp:Int, Meantemp:Int, Mintemp:Int)
    def parseLine(line:String):TempData = {
        val p = line.split(",")
        TempData(p(1).toInt, p(3).toString, p(5).toDouble, p(6).toInt, p(8).toInt, p(10).toInt)
    }

    //> parseLine: (line: String)Tests.TempData
    parseLine("Verizon, 2017, Alpha, October, gentlemen, 10.3, 5, Dallas, 67, schools, 42")
    //> res0: Tests.TempData = TempData(2017, October, 10.3, 5, 67, 42)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The defined function `parseLine(line: String)` takes `String` type arguments, and you have passed it correctly. The confusion is that you are considering the numbers present in the string as integers(Int) which is incorrect. The numbers present in the string are of type `String` only because you have enclosed them in quotes. You can also reason out for using `toInt` for converting the the numbers from `String` to `Int` type.

Answer (score 0):

Your function takes one single `String` as an argument..

```
def parseLine(line: String): TempData
```

And one single `String` is exactly what is passed to it:

```
scala> "Verizon,2017,Alpha,October,gentlemen,10.3,5,Dallas,67,schools,42"
res0: String = Verizon,2017,Alpha,October,gentlemen,10.3,5,Dallas,67,schools,42
```

The numbers are just plain text and are a part of that `String`, there are no integers involved. It's the body of your function that splits the `String` and extracts `Int`s from it.

edit: regarding the title of your post: all of that has nothing to do with your `TempData` case class. It seems that you are confusing the call of the case class constructor with the call to `parseLine`.

Comment: But "Verizon,2017,Alpha,October,gentlemen,10.3,5,Dallas,67,schools,42" is what was input in the function  and it is not a string. It's a mix of strings and integers.

Comment: I'm not worried about the title. I just typed something in there to be able to post my question. My real question is bout what is input in the function.

Comment: It is a `String`. Those numbers are just text and part of the same `String`. Try to understand the difference between `val a: Int = 42` and `val b: String = "42"` (note the quotations marks).

Comment: I see now. Thank you very much!